# What is the principal branch of the complex arcsine, in simple terms?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, inverse-function

By simple, I mean something akin to $\{z: -\pi < \mathrm{Im}\, z \le  \pi\}$  for the logarithm or $\{z: -\pi/2 < \mathrm{Arg}\, z \le \pi/2\}$ for the square root.

I am aware of the answer, "the range of $z \mapsto -i\,\mathrm{Log}(iz + \sqrt{1-z^2})$", where one uses the principal branch of the square root, but I have having trouble sketching that region.  Clearly, it is not the $-i$ times the principal branch of the logarithm (*i.e.*, $\{z: -\pi < \mathrm{Re}\, z \le \pi\}$), as sine is not one-to-one on that region.  The trouble lies in figuring out what the principal branch of  $z \mapsto iz + \sqrt{1-z^2}$ is.

Before looking at other sources, I tried determining a branch of the arcsine from the relation, $\sin(x + iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y$.  From this, I got $\{z: |\mathrm{Re} \, z| < \pi/2\} \cup \{z: \mathrm{Re}\, z=\pm \pi/2, \mathrm{Im}\,z \ge 0\}$ as a natural candidate.  (I *think* that's a branch, isn't it?  That is, I've convinced myself that sine provides a bijection from this region to the entire complex plane, but I still doubt myself a little.)  But this turns out not to be the principal branch, for $\mathrm{Arcsin}(2) = \pi/2 - i\ln(2+\sqrt{3})$, with a negative imaginary part.  ($\sin[\pi/2 + i\ln(2+\sqrt{3})]$ is indeed 2.) It turns out that $\mathrm{sgn \, Im\, Arcsin}\, a = -\mathrm{sgn}\,a$ when $a$  is a real number whose magnitude exceeds unity.  This maintains $\mathrm{Arcsin}(-z)= -\mathrm{Arcsin}\,z$.  So now I hypothesize that the principal branch is almost the one I suggested as my natural candidate above.  Just replace the positive imaginary parts with their negatives when the real part is $\pi/2$.  Haven't proved this, though.  (Somehow, it would feel more natural to me if the signs of the real and imaginary parts matched on these boundaries.)

This comes up because, as a teacher and tutor of precalculus, I often remark in passing that arcsin(2) is undefined until you get to complex analysis (which is never for almost all of my students), where things gets really hairy. I haven't done complex analysis in years, though I was assigned to teach it to undergraduates once. Just got me wondering.  I've tried very hard, but, surprisingly, I have been unable to find an answer to my question on the 'net.

Comment: $2$ doesn;t belong to the principal branch domain as that is $\mathbb C -((-\infty,-1] \cup [1, \infty))$ with image being the strip $-\pi/2 < \Re z< \pi/2$; of course, you can make a branch of the arcsine to be defined at $2$ by connecting $-1, 1, \infty$ in such a way to avoid $2$ but the natural way is simply the way described above (the real line excluding $(-1,1)$)

Comment: in general, any Jordan arc $J$ connecting $-1,1, \infty$ will do to get a branch of arcsine on $\mathbb C -J$ (similarly to the fact that any Jordan arc $K$ connecting $0, \infty$ will do to get a logarithm on $\mathbb C -K$) as $\pm 1, \infty$ are the branch points of the arcsine

Comment: I see I had some misunderstandings:  1)  A branch is a function, not just its range, and 2) a branch has a connected open set as its domain, and the function is analytic on this domain.  In particular, the range of the principal branch of the logarithm is {z:  |Im z| < $\pi$}, without the upper boundary.  Still, $\pi i$ and $i$ are generally known as the respective principal *values* of the logarithm and square root of -1, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is an answer for *the* principal branch; that is, I'm not sure that there is a widely accepted convention.  Someone told you that $ \arcsin 2 = \pi / 2 - \mathrm i \ln ( 2 + \sqrt 3 ) $, but someone else might tell you something else.  But I'll answer based on three things that you stated in your question: $ \arcsin z = - \mathrm i \ln ( \mathrm i z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } ) $; $ z \in \operatorname { ran } ( \ln ) $ iff $ - \pi < \Im z \leq \pi $; and $ z \in \operatorname { ran } ( \surd ) $ iff $ \Re z \geq 0 $ and $ \Re z > 0 $ if $ \Im z < 0 $.  Then the answer is as you were suspecting: $ z \in \operatorname { ran } ( \arcsin ) $ iff: $ - \pi / 2 \leq \Re z \leq \pi / 2 $, $ \Re z > - \pi / 2 $ if $ \Im z < 0 $, and $ \Re z < \pi / 2 $ if $ \Im z > 0 $.  Here is a graph [from Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v954anbfru) (with $ x = \Re z $ and $ y = \Im z $):
[image: A Desmos graph, with the vertical strip where −π/2 < x < π/2 shaded in red with dashed red borders, a solid blue half-line (covering the dashed red border) where x = −π/2 and y > 0, a solid green dot where x = −π/2 and y = 0, a solid black dot where x = π/2 and y = 0, and a solid purple half-line (again covering the dashed red border) where x = π/2 and y < 0]

To see that this is correct, let me show where each part comes from.  First of all, if $ z = \pm 1 $, then $ \arcsin z = \pm \pi / 2 $; you know that this is true if you're working in the real numbers, but it's also what the formula gives: $ 1 - z ^ 2 = 0 $, so $ \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } = 0 $, so $ \mathrm i z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } = \pm \mathrm i $, so $ \ln ( \mathrm i z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } ) = \pm \mathrm i \pi / 2 $, so $ - \mathrm i \ln ( \mathrm i z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } ) = \pm \pi / 2 $.  So these are the black and green dots in the picture above.

Next, if $ z $ is real with $ \lvert z \rvert > 1 $, we have $ z ^ 2 > 1 $ so that $ 1 - z ^ 2 < 0 $, so we can rewrite $ \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } $ as $ \mathrm i \sqrt { z ^ 2 - 1 } $, making $ \mathrm i z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } = \mathrm i ( z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } ) $, a purely imaginary number.  A bit of calculus or a suggestive graph will show that the values taken by $ z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } $ when $ z > 1 $ consist of the real numbers greater than $ 1 $, so when we multiply this by $ \mathrm i $ and take the logarithm, we get $ \pi / 2 $ as the imaginary part but any positive real number as the real part.  Then multiplying this logarithm by $ - \mathrm i $, we get a number whose real part is $ \pi / 2 $ and whose imaginary part is negative, so this is the purple half-line in the graph above.  Similarly (but less obviously, so a graph really helps here), the values of $ z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } $ when $ z < 1 $ consist of the real numbers strictly between $ - 1 $ and $ 0 $, so when we multiply this by $ \mathrm i $ and take the logarithm, we get $ - \pi / 2 $ as the imaginary part and any negative real number as the real part.  Then multiplying this logarithm by $ - \mathrm i $, we get a number whose real part is $ - \pi / 2 $ and whose imaginary part is positive, so this is the blue half-line in the graph above.

Any other value of $ z $ gives us a value of $ \mathrm i z + \sqrt { 1 - z ^ 2 } $ with a positive real part (see [How can we show that $\mathrm{Re}(z + \sqrt{1+z^2}) \ge 0$ for all complex $z$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349910/how-can-we-show-that-mathrmrez-sqrt1z2-ge-0-for-all-complex-z) for why), so that its logarithm has an imaginary part strictly between $ - \pi / 2 $ and $ \pi / 2 $.  Then when we multiply this logarithm by $ - \mathrm i $, we get a number whose real part is strictly between $ \pi / 2 $ and $ - \pi / 2 $, so in the shaded red strip.  I won't go through the work to show that *all* of this strip is included, but you basically think about where the boundary could be and see that it can only happen when the real part of the arcsine is approaching $ \pm \pi / 2 $.

Comment: “Another values of $z$ give a value of $iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}$ with a positive real part” since these other values of $z$ include all numbers with a non-zero imaginary part, since you’ve only covered reals thus far, I’m not sure how to see this, or that it is even true.

Comment: @FShrike :  I guess this is less obvious in general than when $z$ is real.  The most extreme case is when $z=\mathrm iy$ for some positive real $y$, so that $\mathrm iz=-y$. But even then, $\sqrt{1-z^2}=\sqrt{1+y^2}>\sqrt{y^2}=y$, so that $\mathrm iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}>0$.  It seems intuitively obvious that the general case lies between these, but it was harder than I expected to calculate this, so I'll add to the answer.

Comment: I notice you take the trouble to make i in math roman.  Why?  Not being critical; just curious.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349910/how-can-we-show-that-mathrmrez-sqrt1z2-ge-0-for-all-complex-z .

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn :  Great, I'll put a link to this into the question.  (I had a much messier calculation showing this that I was trying to clean up, but the answer that you got is better than what I have.

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn :  About the formatting:  This is more common among engineers, and in my experience more common in the UK than in the USA, but even though I'm an American mathematician, I like it.  The idea is that italics are for symbols with a local variable meaning, while symbols with a constant global meaning are upright.  Then one can distinguish at a glance, for example, the imaginary unit $\mathrm i$ from an indexing variable $i$.  See https://nhigham.com/2016/01/28/typesetting-mathematics-according-to-the-iso-standard/ for some discussion.